# JOIN two tables with one primary key and composite keys

Tags: sql-server, join, composite-primary-key

I have two theoretical questions about the use of JOIN in two different situations:

1. I have `table1` with one column as its PK (`prod_ID`) and `table2` with two columns as its PK (`Prod_ID, START_DATE`). What's the difference in using join between this case and two tables with only one column for PK?
2. I have 3 tables. Table1 with one PK(prod_ID), table2 and table3 have the same composite keys which are prod_ID,DATE,CODE. How can I manage the use of JOIN if I have to select data from all of the three tables?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Don't mix up keys with joins - primary keys define the rules by which data can be stored in a table. One field in a primary key: that key field can be stored *once* in the table. Two fields in a primary key means that the combination of the two fields can be stored once, but one primary key field can be stored several times along with different values of the second key field.

The number of fields in the second table's PK is not relevant to the join. Joining the first table and the second table should give multiple lines with the same key field. Similarly, having three key fields in the third table doesn't matter to the join.